# Android.mk change local C include directory depending on file

Tags: c, android-ndk, android.mk

I am building a dynamic library (.so) file for android with around 100 local c files.  The files all include a file `c_macros.h`, but the `c_macros.h` in question changes for different groups of files.  For example, `foo0.c` and `bar0.c` need to include `c_macros.h` in the directory `0/` whereas `foo1.c` and `bar1.c` need to include `c_macros.h` in the directory `1/`.

I see that one can define `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` for the entirety of a compilation so that all .o files will use those local includes.  However, can the `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` be specified for a single file (or a group of files) and then change so that the right directories can be included for the right files?

One solution is just to build different .so files depending on which `c_macros.h` is being used, but this adds an overhead of around 10KB for each .so file, so I'd like to squash everything in one big .so file if possible, but then I'd need to sort out the `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can build it into separate static libraries (where you can easily set different `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` for each), and just build one single .so file that includes the static libraries. When linking the final .so file, this doesn't incur any extra overhead (the object files from static libraries behave just as normal individual object files).